# Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xa0 (at char #720, byte #37)

Tags: hadoop, hadoop3

I have installed hadoop-3.3.4 in Ubuntu 22.04.1 virtual machine using virtual box 7. I have configured the `core-site.xml`. But, it cannot run the format of namenode.

The code for `core-site.xml` is stipulated below

```
<configuration>
  <property>
     <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
     <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

But, the error is happened:

`2023-01-15 21:39:44,393 ERROR conf.Configuration: error parsing conf core-site.xml`
`com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xa0 (at char #719, byte #37)`.

I wonder there is a bug in hadoop-3.3.4.

Comment: If you think it's a bug (which I doubt), then did you try 3.3.3?

Comment: No, I didn't. Maybe I need to re-install the hadoop.